# How can i make several "drop down menu triggers" in one script in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets with TWO sheets inside.
first page - collecting data from a form. second page - pulling specific data from page one. same specific cells from the Rows selected & adds the information on new rows in Sheet2.

in page one, on the first cell of each row i have a dropdown menu that suppose to trigger that Sendd script - that sends that data to the second sheet.

I figured out how to activate each of the dropdown menus as a trigger to activate the script. but i need to write a separate script for each one of the drop down menus separately.

**Is it possible to make all of the drop down menus on Column A as a Triggers with one script?**

Here's the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {                           //////menu trigers function
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A9') {      //////Menu cell
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ORDERS');  /////// those 2 lines make the cell
      var cellname = sheet.getRange(9,1);                                /////// go back to "Quick Access"
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
      cellname.setValue('');  
    }
  }
}



function SendClear() {
  Sendd();
  clear1();
}

function Sendd() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("ORDERS"); //Data entry Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("TakeAway"); //Data Sheet
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E9").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 3, 1, 3).setValues(values);  //inputs the data from "INPUT" into "DATA". (+1 = adds new line. 1 = offset starting cell
  
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `but i have a lot of rows and want to make all of them to triggers in one script` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hey Tanaike, thanks for replaying!
in the first sheet, i havelet's say 10 rows. in each row there's information like name, family name, phone, address and more. 
on the start of each row i have a tick box (or a drop down menu), that when i press on that box i want that specific cells from that row will be sent to a new row in the other sheet. 

is it make more sense? 
Thanks

Comment: I edited the question, to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, I think that the dropdown list can be also used. But in this case, when you use the checkbox instead of the dropdown list, I think that the situation becomes simpler. How about this?

Comment: It doesn't matter for me if it will a check box or a drop down menu. the main issue is that i need to write for each one of them an individual 'Send' Script. and what i would want to, if it's possible, is that that script will be able for the range of A9:A.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `It doesn't matter for me if it will a check box or a drop down menu. the main issue is that i need to write for each one of them an individual 'Send' Script. and what i would want to, if it's possible, is that that script will be able for the range of A9:A.`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, the checkbox is used for running the script. So please insert the checkboxes to the cells "A9:A". By this, when the checkbox is checked, the script works and when the script is finished, the checkbox is unchecked.

```js
function onEdit(o) {
  var range = o.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "ORDERS" || range.columnStart != 1 || range.rowStart < 9 || !range.isChecked()) return;
  var [c,,e,,,,,j] = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 3, 1, 8).getValues()[0];
  o.source.getSheetByName("TakeAway").appendRow([c, j, e]);
  sheet.getRangeList([`C${range.rowStart}`, `E${range.rowStart}`, `J${range.rowStart}`]).clearContent(); // When you want to clear the cells of "C", "E", "J", after the values were copied, please use this line.
  range.uncheck();
}
```

- When the checkbox of "A9:A" is checked, the script is copied from the columns "C", "J", "E" in order (this is from your script.) to the destination sheet. The value is appended to the destination sheet.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the source sheet name and the destination sheet name are `ORDERS` and `TakeAway`. This is from your script. So when you change these sheet names, please modify the above script.
- This script used the event object by running with OnEdit trigger. So when you directly run this script with the script editor, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

#### About some unclear points, I guessed as follows.

- I couldn't understand the function `clear1()` in your script. So I guessed that you wanted to clear the cells of columns "C", "E" and "J", after the values were copied. So I added a script of `sheet.getRangeList([`C${range.rowStart}`,` E${range.rowStart}`,` J${range.rowStart}`]).clearContent();`. If my guess was not correct, please remove this.

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! it is looking good and working. right now the information shows on the second Sheet on column A. can i offset it to start from column C ?

And I do get an error when running the script:
```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2
```
i believe this is what you talked about

Comment: @Ita By the way, about `And I do get an error when running the script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ Code.gs:2`, in this case, I'm worried that you might have directly run the script. In that case, such an error occurs as I had mentioned in my answer. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tanaike!

This is the Answer:

```
function onEdit(o) {
  var range = o.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "ORDERS" || range.columnStart != 1 || range.rowStart < 9 || !range.isChecked()) return;
  var [c,,e,,,,,j] = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 3, 1, 8).getValues()[0];
  o.source.getSheetByName("TakeAway").appendRow([null,null,c, j, e]);  sheet.getRangeList([`C${range.rowStart}`, `E${range.rowStart}`, `J${range.rowStart}`]).clearContent(); // When you want to clear the cells of "C", "E", "J", after the values were copied, please use this line.
  range.uncheck();
}
```

to make a cell offset to th input information i changed this line:

```
  o.source.getSheetByName("TakeAway").appendRow([c, j, e]);
```

to this:

```
  o.source.getSheetByName("TakeAway").appendRow([null,null,c, j, e]);
```

Thank you Tanaike!